# Selenium Webdriver - Toggle switch click is not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I suppose to test toggle switch element to on and off, but while sending click to the element I am getting `Clickable element not found` error. I have corrected my code with chain action and JavaScript executor as well but no use. Still I am getting same error.

Before click:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-12 apex-col-auto">
    <div class="t-Form-fieldContainer rel-col  apex-item-wrapper plugin-org.armbruster-it.apex.yesno.flipswitch " id="P42_INTERPRETOR_REQUIRED_CONTAINER">
      <div class="t-Form-labelContainer col col-3">
        <label for="P42_INTERPRETOR_REQUIRED" id="P42_INTERPRETOR_REQUIRED_LABEL" class="t-Form-label">Does the person require an interpreter?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="t-Form-inputContainer col col-9">
        <!-- start flipswitch plugin -->
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="middle">
                  <div class="toggle-light" id="S_P42_INTERPRETOR_REQUIRED" style="height: 20px; width: 70px;">
                    <div class="toggle-slide">
                      <div class="toggle-inner" style="width: 120px; margin-left: -50px;">
                        <div class="toggle-on" style="height: 20px; width: 60px; text-indent: -6.66667px; line-height: 20px;">Yes</div>
                        <div class="toggle-blob" style="height: 20px; width: 20px; margin-left: -10px;"></div>
                        <div class="toggle-off active" style="height: 20px; width: 60px; margin-left: -10px; text-indent: 6.66667px; line-height: 20px;">No</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td valign="middle">
                  <input type="hidden" name="P42_INTERPRETOR_REQUIRED" id="P42_INTERPRETOR_REQUIRED" value="0">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        <!-- end flipswitch plugin -->
        <span id="P42_INTERPRETOR_REQUIRED_error_placeholder" class="a-Form-error" data-template-id="5324259027594930_ET"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After click:

```
<div class="toggle-light" id="S_P42_INTERPRETOR_REQUIRED" style="height: 20px; width: 70px;">
    <div class="toggle-slide">
        <div class="toggle-inner" style="width: 120px; margin-left: 0px;">
            <div class="toggle-on active" style="height: 20px; width: 60px; text-indent: -6.66667px; line-height: 20px;">Yes</div>
            <div class="toggle-blob" style="height: 20px; width: 20px; margin-left: -10px;"/>
            <div class="toggle-off" style="height: 20px; width: 60px; margin-left: -10px; text-indent: 6.66667px; line-height: 20px;">No</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show the html code before and after the click ?

Comment: And the code and the error message + stack trace